# Combining functions and finding domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x) = \ln (2 - x)$

$g(x) = \frac {1}{√x}$

I am asked to find the domain of $\frac gf$

So $\frac gf$ would be $\frac {1}{√x}$ over $\ln (2 - x)
$
which would be $\frac{\ln (2-x)}{√x}$

so the domain is $0 < x < 2$

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: $g(x)/f(x)$ is not the function you wrote. Check it.

Comment: Edited. I think my domain is still right?

Comment: No, $g/f$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\frac g f = \frac1{\sqrt x \log (2-x)}$$

and we need

- for the definition of $f$: $$2-x>0$$
- for the definition of $g$: $$x\ge 0$$
- for the definition of $f/g$: $$\sqrt x \log (2-x)\neq 0$$

for there we obtain that

- $x>0$
- $2-x>0$
- $2-x\neq 1$

Solve that system to find the domain.